# how to call synchronous webservice in java or increase the value i after getting webservice response?

Tags: java, android

I am send post request in loop like ..I am giving you psedo code .Actually I need some  basic example for synchronise  call .In other word in my example 10 request fire simultaneously and get the web service result.Is there any way to call  synchronised type.Mean I need to increase value of I when I get the web service response ..when I=0 it call web service and get response then it increase the value .i=1 .Not send all request simultaneously .send step by step .

```
for (int i=0;i<10 ;i++){
//get data from data base 
//get data from data base using i
JsonObject  data =SELECT from Data* where ID=i
//call post request in another thread
callpostresquest(data)

}


callpostresquest(JsonObject onj){


Thread t=new Theard(){
run (){
// call web service when I got response I call back one method 
callback(respone);
}

}t.start()
}
```

// call method in main screen

```
getWebserviceresponse (String response){

//get the wevservice response ..Then I need to increase value of i variable  here how ?


}
```

Comment: why do you want a sync. call? this will block the ui thread

Comment: yes .that why i take in another thread

Comment: thread or asynctask? don't use usual threads in android. in a asynctask you can use httprequest as you do in java.

Comment: then why are you taggin that with android?!

Comment: actually both using java that why i am asking

Comment: that's the wrong way. both platforms have specific methods for that, then why didn't you just tag blackberry... that's like asking, how do i accelerate on a car, when you acutally wanna know how to accelerate on a plane, because both are vehicle...

Answer (score 0):

It is just possible to add t.join() after the t.start().
This causes your code to wait for a thread to end (the single one that was started)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit). First you can map your json objects to a model for further working. Second you are then able to call async as well sync calls from the interface which you have to declare for retrofit. I assume you are using a REST server? Then it's a perfect fit. Remember that you are blocking the UI thread when calling sync calls, therefore I would suggest to use async calls.